# Spring Boot - Preventing files from completely being loaded before security rules check

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, spring-security

I have a `Spring-Boot` (1.4.9) controller for file upload with some `Spring-Security` rules. Everything is working as expected but **Spring waits for entire file to be uploaded and then checks security rules for the request**, so it can happen that a user upload a 2GB file to know that he/she doesn't have the enough privilege or some other problems exist.

What's the best way to avoid these scenarios?

Comment: Did you try [`MultipartProperties#setResolveLazily`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.7.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartProperties.html#setResolveLazily-boolean-)?

Comment: Do you use CSRF?